# How to show Master-Detail Informations in a collapsable ListView

Tags: wpf, listbox, master-detail

I have a class that describes a certain task. This "task"-Class has a list of substeps.

What I wanted to do is to show these Informations in a ListView where the task-description should be used as the Groupheader and the substeps as the details

Also I wanted to be able to collapse and expand these groups.

Here is what I tried so far (simplified, but you'll get the idea hopefully):

```
public class Task : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string Description;
   public ObservableCollection<String> substeps;
   ...
}
```

in the Viewmodel :

```
Task t = new Task();
t.Description = "Task1";
t.substeps.Add("substep 1");
t.substeps.Add("substep 2");
...

Tasks = new CollectionViewSource { Source = TaskList }; //TaskList is just a ObservableCollection<Task>
Tasks.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Description"));
```

in xaml:

```
<s:SurfaceListBox Width="500" Height="1000" ItemsSource="{Binding TaskList.View}">
                <s:SurfaceListBox.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="ContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Expander Header="{Binding Description}" IsExpanded="True">
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </s:SurfaceListBox.Resources>
                <s:SurfaceListBox.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
                </s:SurfaceListBox.GroupStyle>
                <s:SurfaceListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding substeps}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </s:SurfaceListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </s:SurfaceListBox>
```

The Result is a Listbox with my collapsed item. If I expand it, instead of each step I only see "(Listing)"

Do I have to build a class with the substeps and the description in it, and group by the description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<s:SurfaceListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding substeps} />
    </DataTemplate>
</s:SurfaceListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Your problem is that the string binding to the `ObservableCollection` will just do a `ToString()` on that collection. You need iterate through the collection and display each item. By using the `ItemsControl` as I have done, you can also `DataTemplate` each subtask as you see fit.

**ControlTemplate Binding**

The `Expander` header binding will not work because it is inside a `ControlTemplate` which is inside the `Style`. The `DataContext` for the control template will not be your `ViewModel` but the control (i.e. `SurfaceListBox`) itself. Similar question is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d3c939ae-d5a2-442c-906b-5fd53043566e).

There are two ways you can fix this.

1.Use `DataTemplate`

```
<s:SurfaceListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Expander Header="{Binding Description}"
                  IsExpanded="True" >
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding substeps} />
        </Expander >
    </DataTemplate>
</s:SurfaceListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

2.Use `TemplatedParent` binding

```
<Expander Header="{Binding Content.Description, , RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
          IsExpanded="True">
```

I personally recommend option 1.

Comment: Ah that does the trick. Thank you. But one last question: the {Binding Description} for the Expander Header doesn't seem to work. It is always empty (Header="test" shows "test") Description is a property of my Task-class. Do I have to set a datasource somewhere? It is weird because the {Binding substeps} works just fine.